# Mockito: how to test that a constructor was called?

Tags: java, constructor, mocking, mockito

I am using Mockito to test methods within my Java application.

How can I test that a constructor was called once?

I am trying to do a verification similar to this:

```
verify(myClass, times(1)).doSomething(anotherObject);
```

But I can't verify that the constructor was called as it doesn't have a method similar to e.g. `doSomething()`.

Comment: Um, you can't get an Object if you don't call it's constructor; that's a language feature.

Comment: please explain what you mean

Comment: You should describe what it is that you're actually trying to test, that made you think you needed to mock a constructor. I wouldn't be surprised if there is no real need for it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can't be done with Mockito, since the object being created is not a mocked object.  This also means that you won't be able to verify anything on that new object either.

I've worked around this scenario in the past by using a `Factory` to create the object rather than newing it up.  You're then able to mock the `Factory` to return the object required for your test.

Whether you're happy changing your design to suit your tests is up to you!

Comment: This seems the best fix. Ill look into using a Factory class in future to solve this

Comment: Introducing a factory to work around a limitation in the mocking library... that's obviously not a good solution. Instead, I would suggest to avoid the supposed need to mock the class being instantiated from the SUT. Usually, a better test with no mocking is possible.

Comment: verify(MyClass.class,times(1)).newInstance();

Answer (score 29):

You can do it with Mockito and PowerMockito.

Say you have ClassUnderTest with a constructor

```
public class ClassUnderTest {
    String name;
    boolean condition;

    public ClassUnderTest(String name, boolean condition) {
       this.name = name;
       this.condition = condition;
       init();
    }

    ...
}
```

And another class that calls that constructor

```
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() { } 

    public void createCUTInstance() {
       // ...
       ClassUnderTest cut = new ClassUnderTest("abc", true);
       // ...
    }

    ...
}
```

At the Test class we could...

(1) use PowerMockRunner and cite both target classes above in the PrepareForTest annotation:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ClassUnderTest.class, MyClass.class })
public class TestClass {
```

(2) intercept the constructor to return a mock object:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    ClassUnderTest cutMock = Mockito.mock(ClassUnderTest.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassUnderTest.class)
                .withArguments(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyBoolean())
                .thenReturn(cutMock);
}
```

(3) validate the constructor call:

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
    // prepare
    MyClasss myClass = new MyClass();

    // execute
    myClass.createCUTInstance();

    // checks if the constructor has been called once and with the expected argument values:
    String name = "abc";
    String condition = true;
    PowerMockito.verifyNew(ClassUnderTest.class).withArguments(name, condition);
}
```

Comment: I think the sequence of the last two lines in your testMethod() should swap. like this: new ClassUnderTest(name, condition); PowerMockito.verifyNew(ClassUnderTest.class);

Comment: @WillieZ, thank you so much for calling my attention about this test method! In truth, that previous last command was not really needed. The original idea was to test the constructor call with certain specific argument values, in a method under test called in the execute phase.  I've just rewritten the code to express my original intention. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 12):

With Mockito can do something

```
try (MockedConstruction<MyClass> myclass = Mockito.mockConstruction(
        MyClass.class)) {
    ........
    Assert.assertEquals(1, myClass.constructed().size());
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.. and with no need to add another dependancy!

Answer (score 2):

`verify()` method waits for mocked object(already created object). And `constructor` can not be called on `created object`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with Mockito and sounds like a bad design.

You can use a factory and pass it to the object under test. After that you can easily mock the factory and verify that its create method was called.

By directly creating objects in your code you are making a hard dependency to concrete implementations, which makes the code harder and sometimes impossible to unit test. This is addressed with Dependency Injection (DI) and Inversion of Control (IoC).

Answer (score 0):

A constructor won't return an object if it failed... and if it fails the program will most likely crash.

Tough i suppose this would do it:

```
Object obj = null;

obj = new Object();

if (obj == null) {
  //... Didn't Work
} else {
  //... Worked
}
```

Comment: OP isn't asking how to verify that the constructor works, but how to verify that some other code indeed calls the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you will not be able to mock the constructor with mockito, but using powermockito you should be able to and then verify it. Setup would be something like this

```
public class MyClass{

   public MyClass(String name){}

   public void doSomethingUseFul(){
      //.......
   }

}

public class Helper {

   public void goHelp(){
       new MyClass("apple").doSomethingUseFul();
   } 

}
```

//Mock

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
    public class MockMyClass {
    @InjectMocks
    private Helper helper;

        @Test
        public void testDoSomethingUseFul() {
             MyClass  c = mock(MyClass.class); 
             doNothing().when(c).doSomethingUseFul();
             PowerMockito.whenNew(MyClass. class).withArguments(anyString()).thenReturn(c);
             helper.goHelp(); 
             verifyNew(MyClass.class).withArguments(anyString())


        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

We can test using Mockito with

```
verify(MyClass.class,times(1)).newInstance();
```

Comment: This does not work. The first argument passed to `verify()` must be a mock.